# Fetching data from json array and comparing

Tags: php, arrays, json

Hello i have a json array which contains an array structure. I am trying to fetch the value against a particular key. Like getting a key with name lower and value 9226. I have implemented for each loop but i cannot get into it. There is some issue in my comparison statement.

```
   {
"tax_structure": [
    {
        "tax_data": {
            "lower": 0,
            "upper": 9225,
            "tax_rate": 10,
            "amount": 0
        }
    },
    {
        "tax_data": {
            "lower": 9226,
            "upper": 37450,
            "tax_rate": 15,
            "amount": 922.50
        }
    }
 ]
 }
```

Php file:

```
  <?php
      $expense=10000;

$str_data = file_get_contents("data.json");
$data = json_decode($str_data,true);

foreach ($data["tax_structure"] as $tax_data) {
    foreach ($tax_data["tax_data"] as $key => $value) {
        if($key=="lower" && $expense>$value) & ($key=="upper" &&$expense<$value)
        {
            //do something if expenses value falls between the lower and upper limit values of keys
        }

     }
   }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking for something like the following.
There is no need for the second for loop.

```
$expense = 10000;

$str_data = file_get_contents("data.json");
$data = json_decode($str_data,true);

foreach ($data["tax_structure"] as $tax_data_object) {
    if($tax_data_object['tax_data']['lower'] < $expense && $tax_data_object['tax_data']['upper'] > $expense){
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

You should try `print_r($data);`. This will show the structure of your data array.

If you examine the structure of your data the above code should be obvious.

If it isn't, here are a few sources for further learning:

[PHP: Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

[JSON introduction](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp)

Comment: Thanks it works. wats the logic. Looping into json array seems tough if you could explain. Can we use for loops too. thanks

Comment: You could theoretically use a for loop in this situation, but there would be no advantage in doing so. It would need more code and would be slower.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <?php
$expense = 10000;

$str_data = file_get_contents("data.json");
$data     = json_decode($str_data, true);

foreach ($data["tax_structure"] as $tax_data) {
    foreach ($tax_data["tax_data"] as $key => $value) {

        if ($key == "lower" && $expense > $value) {

            echo "Key is lower and the value is " . $value . "<br>";
        }

        if ($key == "upper" && $expense < $value) {

            echo "Key is upper and the value is " . $value . "<br>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

You cant do this `if($key=="lower" && $expense>$value) & ($key=="upper" &&$expense<$value)`

Comment: it doesn't work.. it's not getting into the loop i guess. it doesnot print echo command.

Comment: Does this code work? Maybe your data.json is in a different directory? And does it display an error?

Comment: the problem is we with loop. you just need one loop. right now it prints lower and upper values for all the json array.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?